# Using MSSQL server freeware with Sharepoint

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, sql-server

i recently downloaded Windows Server 2016 and sharepoint 2013, and then i went on to download SQLServer Express. Here is what i want to know. Can i use the freeware version of SQL Server together with sharepoint 2013 which i downloaded differently.

I would like to know

Comment: Installing SharePoint 2013 as a stand-alone server will install SQL Express by default as db engine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can use the SQL server express edition with SharePoint 2013 server. But keep in mind their are limitation with express addition, i.e. maximum storage capacity is 10Gb.

check this blog for the complete installation steps: How to [Install SharePoint Foundation 2013 with SQL Server 2014 Express](https://www.netometer.com/blog/?p=1442)